# Overflow fault 6 VBA While-loop

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, overflow

First of all thanks for helping me.
I programmed a Sub and I always get an Overflow fault 6. Its in the line where it says `While x<160`. I cannot do more then 160. E.g. If I do 170 Ill get the fault. But I would like to `do While x<1000`

The goal is to sum up duration times. Eg. On 1/2/2017 we had 2 downtime for electrical reason, first was 2 minutes, second was 10 minutes.

This macro is making a summary for the 1/2/17 saying that we had 12min downtime because electrical reasons.

I don't do that in a professional way, but this would make my work so much easier! Its working. I only get this annoying Overflow fault if I want to write in large numbers.

```
Sub sumuptheduration()


    'Then sum up all the duration times

   Dim a As Integer
   Dim b As Integer
   Dim c As Integer
   Dim x As Long
   Dim summe As Variant
   Dim valuecells As Range


   a = 1
   b = 2
   c = 0
   x = 1

   Set valuecells = Worksheets(1).Range("P2")


   Do While Worksheets(1).Range("C" & b).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("C" & b+a).Value And Worksheets(1).Range("J" & b).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("J" & b + a).Value

        Set valuecells = Worksheets(1).Range("P" & b & ":P" & a + b)
        a = a + 1


    Loop


    Worksheets(1).Range("S" & a + (b - 1)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(valuecells)




    b = a + 2
    c = a + 2
    a = 1




    Dim y As Integer
    y = 0






   While x < 160


    Do While Worksheets(1).Range("C" & b).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("C" & b + a).Value And Worksheets(1).Range("J" & b).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("J" & b + a).Value

        Set valuecells = Worksheets(1).Range("P" & b & ":P" & c + a)

        a = a + 1

    Loop





    Worksheets(1).Range("S" & c + (a - 1)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(valuecells) 'Writes the Sum into the correct Cell (last one of combination)


        'This if clause checks if there are "Single combinations" because single combinations do not go through the do while at the top


        If Worksheets(1).Range("J" & b).Value <> Worksheets(1).Range("J" & b + a).Value And Worksheets(1).Range("J" & b).Value <> Worksheets(1).Range("J" & b + (a - 2)).Value Or Worksheets(1).Range("C" & b).Value <> Worksheets(1).Range("C" & b + a).Value And Worksheets(1).Range("C" & b).Value <> Worksheets(1).Range("C" & b + (a - 2)).Value Then


            Worksheets(1).Range("S" & b).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("P" & b).Value

        Else

        End If


    'Change the variables into correct way for the next passing of the do while clause
    x = x + 1 'causes that do while is not just one time passes
    b = c + a
    c = c + a 'temporary variable to not forget the old b during the next passing of the do while
    a = 1 'at the end of every passing a tells you how much times you needed to pass the do while, so you have to reset it every time



    Wend

      End Sub





here
```

Comment: Try using `Dim x As Double`

Comment: @0m3r That is unlikely to be the issue

Comment: No that's not the problem

Comment: `While x < 160` isn't a line which can trigger an overflow error. The code is on the convoluted side so it is hard to see where the issue is. Can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you sure the overflow isn't occurring on the line **after** `While x < 160` - I can see ways that that could happen.

Comment: I always get the fault when I change the number 160 to a higher number

Comment: But does the error occur on the `While x < 160` line, or on the line after that?

Answer (score 2):

Change the declarations as follows:

```
 Dim a As Long
 Dim b As Long
 Dim c As Long
```

Do not declare these variables as Integer

Comment: @Bibi `b + a` is probably exceeding 32768.  By making it `Long` instead of `Integer`, you will be able to handle any row in the worksheet.

Comment: Declare them as Long! Please read about VBA variable types. Integer is max 32,768

Comment: If I declare them as Long Excel is not responding anymore

Comment: Because it is looping, this is then reason. it will eventually stop after a long time. You have a logic issue obviously. Please review your Do...Loop

Comment: @Bibi The error 1004 will have occurred when `b + a` was equal to 1048577, because Excel doesn't have a row 1048577.

Comment: @Bibi My guess is that you got to a row `b` which is empty, and every row after it is empty.

Comment: Exactly. Please review the logic. What I would suggest: first get the last row number and store it in a variable. Check if you didn't exceed this value.

Comment: Yes that's true, the table is not endless. That's possibly the problem. I will change that and let you know if this is working.

Comment: It is working! Thank you so much. I just addes While x < 1000 And b <= celast  (celast is the variable for the last row)

Comment: Great it worked! Please mark this question as answered.